# BinaryContent for a pdf is null

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-media-bundle

I am using Sonata Media Bundle to let users upload PDF files. I want to use Imagick to create a preview image of a pdf document. I have a `$media` object that holds information about my pdf.

When I do `die(dump($media))`, I see a media object that includes the following line:

```
#providerReference: "3c4460aae99b0084d08252065bf3eea1817842d9.pdf"
```

... and opening that file via:

```
open -a Preview ./data/storage/faq/0001/01/3c4460aae99b0084d08252065bf3eea1817842d9.pdf
```

... on my mac yields a fully legible PDF.

The problem is that I also see the following line in the browser:

```
#binaryContent: null
```

... which means that I can't dump the binary content into a temporary file for the purpose of having Imagick manipulate it.

**How do I get a file path that I can hand off to Imagick?**

Answer (score 0):

Here is roughly what worked in order to get me a useful reference to a file, complete with valid binary content.

```
public function preUpdate(Document $document)
{
    $media = $document->getMedia();
    if ($media === null) {
        return;
    }
    $mediaName = $media->getName();
    if ($media->getContentType() !== 'application/pdf') {
        return;
    }

    $context = $media->getContext();
    $formats = $pool->getFormatNamesByContext($context);

    if (null === $formats) {
        return;
    }

    $provider = $this->getProvider($media->getProviderName());
    $publicUrls = [];

    $fullFilePath = $provider->getReferenceImage($media);



}

...

private function getPool()
{
    return $this->container->get('sonata.media.pool');
}

...

private function getProvider($name)
{
    return $this->container->get($name);
}
```